# Android - How to save file from server socket to sdcard pdf and jpg...?

Tags: android, sockets

I made server on  my PC and Client on android...I write jpg file through socket and client android read and display successfully. But i want to save that to sdcard. Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void copytoSD() throws IOException{

            //Open your local file as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = //your input Stream

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString+"/filename.jpg";

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }
```